# Zend Framework - View Array - Object Notation

Tags: php, zend-framework

I pass an array to a view, which has code like this:

```
<?php foreach ($this->results as $r): ?>
<div>
<?php echo $this->url(array('id' => $this->escape($r[RecordID]) ....
```

Suppose I want to use object notation:

```
<?php foreach ($this->results as $r): ?>
<div>
<?php echo $this->url(array('id' => $this->escape($r->RecordID) ....
```

Is this possible?

Comment: If `$r` is `object`, then it is possible. If it is an `array`, than it is not.

Comment: I think the important question is, why is it an array to begin with? By casting it you may be curing the symptoms but hiding the issue rather than solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only real option is to cast the array to an object prior to using it this way.

```
  <?php foreach ($this->results as $r): ?>
  <div>

  <?php $r = (object)$r;
        echo $this->url(array('id' => $this->escape($r->RecordID) ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can try with Object to use object array in view like

```
 <?php foreach ($this->arrUserList as $data) { ?>
                 <?php $data = (object)$data; ?>

  <td><?php echo $this->escape($data->userName); ?></td>
```

Let me know if i can help you more.